# How to get powershell to always return a list

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the resolution of the primary monitor on a system. So

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_videocontroller
```

will return either a single object or a list of objects (terminology probably incorrect) which contain the resolutions. If you want to pull a single value, such as .currenthorizontalresolution, you either have to specify

```
(get-wmiobject -class win32_videocontroller).currenthorizontalresolution
```

or

```
(get-wmiobject -class win32_videocontroller)[0].currenthorizontalresolution
```

depending on whether your system has a single monitor, where the first works, or multiple monitors, where the second works.

I'd like to use a single expression... but can't get the syntax right.
I've tried plenty of variations but I cannot work out the syntax to use a single line to get the resolution of the first (or only) monitor.

To be clear this is a powershell syntax issue and not a wmi issue.

EBGreen suggested

```
(,(get-wmiobject -class win32_videocontroller))[0].currenthorizontalresolution
```

but this returns

```
1366
```

on a system with a single monitor and

```
1280
1920
```

on a system with two monitors. The direction is correct and I had tried something similar with selects but not quite right.

Comment: For dual monitors, what do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force it to always return an array with the `'@'` operator:

```
@(get-wmiobject -class win32_videocontroller)[0].currenthorizontalresolution
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I had been trying to work out. Now that you've posted this I seem to remember having to use that syntax some time back and I'd completely forgotten it. I need to write more PS. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will do what you want:

```
(,(get-wmiobject -class win32_videocontroller))[0].currenthorizontalresolution
```

Comment: Where it returns a single object, this converts it to a list - so correct, but on a system with two monitors, where wmi is returning two object, this returns two values.  I'll post this result in the question as it can be formatted.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then. If there are two controllers, I thought that you would want a list of two objects.

Comment: since you can have 1 or more monitors I wanted to be able to select monitor 0 without checking the number of monitors. The issue is that when there is one you get a wmi object, but when there are two you get an array of wmi objects. What I wanted was to always get an array of objects. The @ syntax mentioned above works.